# How to know the screen is fully drawn in iOS

Tags: ios, draw

I am drawing free hand with the code mentioned in below link.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164

Now, I can draw the curve. But what I want is to display an alert once the view is fully drawn with the curves. Any help appreciated.

So far, what I did is that I fetched the color of the CGPoint. But I am not sure how can I add the condition once I know the color of CGPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what you want to achive wirh the CGPoint, but this is how I would do what you want to do:

```
- (void) drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     [super drawInRect:rect];

      //do your drawing

      [self doStuffAfterDrawing];
}

-(void)doStuffAfterDrawing
{
    //here you can launch your alert
}
```